# Click sounds stop spectral subtraction

Tags: noise-cancellation

I'm using a spectral subtractor to eliminate some continuous tones equi spaced in frequency through overlap-add method, some example code in Matlab:

```
%Windowing parameters
NFFT   =N;
WINLEN =N;
WINSTEP=N/2;

overlap=max(WINLEN-WINSTEP,1);
win=@hamming;
ACw=(WINLEN/sum(win(WINLEN))); %Amplitude Correction of window effect

frames = frame_sig(sig,WINLEN, WINSTEP, win); %frame the signal
cspec = fft(frames,NFFT,2); % complex spectrum
pspec=abs(cspec*ACw/N).^2;
phase = angle(cspec);%save the phase

%Using precalculated subtractor nFilt
load('nFilt.mat')
gSub=1.5;subtraction gain, some audio has more level than others

%Subtraction
noise_est =  gSub*nFilt;% noise estimator
clean_spec = pspec-noise_est;%repmat(noise_est,size(pspec,1),1); % subtract noise_est from pspec
clean_spec(clean_spec < 0) = 0; % negative power spectrum is not allowed

%reconstruction 
reconstructed_frames = ifft(  N/ACw*sqrt(clean_spec).*exp(1i*phase) ,NFFT,2);
reconstructed_frames = real(reconstructed_frames(:,1:WINLEN)); 
enhanced_signal = deframe_sig(reconstructed_frames,length(sig),WINLEN,WINSTEP,win);
```

The code does the job correctly except when a loud click sound appears, when this happen that frame doesn't work properly as you can see in this image (top original, bottom subtracted):
[image: top original, bottom subtracted]

I guess this has to be related with the sharp phase change that this "click" sounds imply but, any clue on how to solve it?

All the best

Comment: The only interesting (and difficult) part in such an implementation is the noise estimator, which is not included in your code. So there's nothing we can do or say. In general, spectral subtraction is not very good at suppressing non-stationary noise like clicks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
As I said in my post I'm eliminating continuous tones not a general noise or non-stationary clicks. The sustractor is a simple one which consist on the same continuos tones that you can see in the upper figure (starting at second 2) built upon triang windows of 1Hz bandwidth. I did not post because I though it will be clearer that way.
Any clue about why is not working around the clicks?
All the best